# Set textfield editable in runtime

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a textfield, which should be editable after pressing button:

```
playerName = new TextField();
playerName.autoSize = "left";
playerName.styleSheet = styleSheet;
playerName.type = TextFieldType.DYNAMIC;
playerName.tabEnabled = false;
playerName.maxChars = 14;
playerName.background = false;
playerName.backgroundColor = 0x1e904b;
...
var boldStyleObject:Object = {};
boldStyleObject.fontSize = 12;
boldStyleObject.fontFamily = "Verdana";
boldStyleObject.color = "#ffffff";
boldStyleObject.fontWeight = "bold";
styleSheet.setStyle(".bold", boldStyleObject);
boldStyleName = "bold";
...
playerName.htmlText = "<span class='" + boldStyleName + "'>" + player.name + "</span>";
...
private function ChangeName (event:Event):void
{
    playerName.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
    playerName.background = true;
    playerName.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, DoneEditing);
    stage.focus = playerName;
}
...

private function DoneEditing (event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    var target:TextField = event.target as TextField;

    if (event.keyCode == 27)
    {
        target.text = editBackup;
        DisactivateTextField(target);
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == 13 && target == playerName && playerName.text.length > 3)
    {
        DisactivateTextField(target);
    }
}

private function DisactivateTextField(field:TextField):void
{
    field.type = TextFieldType.DYNAMIC;
    field.background = false;
    field.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, DoneEditing);
}
```

All working fine, except TextField's editability. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in html style. In some reason, `TextField` with htmlText, styled via styleSheet, can't be edited. You should use `TextField.defaultTextFormat` property to style text you whant to edit.

Comment: Oh yeah. You can still use a textformat instance, though. `playerName.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat('Verdana',12,0xffffff,true);` **Note that** the `defaultTextFormat` property applies to the text that gets added *after* it's set.

Answer (score 1):

Pressing a button requires a `MouseEvent`so make sure you're adding the right event listener to yourbutton. Also, make sure you're checking the user input to terminate editing or evaluating the input itself.

```
private function something():void {
    yourBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ChangeName);
}
private function ChangeName(e:MouseEvent):void {
    playerName.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
    playerName.background = true;
    playerName.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,DoneEditing);
    stage.focus = playerName;
}
private function DoneEditing(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER) {
        // do your magic here
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for responce, but ll working fine, exept TextField's editability. I edited question, please, take a look.